# Mapping an array of objects only works on a copy of the array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, sequelize.js

I have the feeling that this is an obscure side of Javascript that I simply do not know or understand.

I'm retrieving an array of objects from a database using Sequelize. It's a relatively complex array, as in contains associations. The array looks like this (it is simplified) :

```json
[
  {
    name: '...',
    director: '...',
    genres: [
      {id: 1, name: 'Mystery'},
      {id: 2, name: 'Thriller'},
    ],
  },
  ...
]
```

I want to map this array so to change the format of `genres` from this:

```json
genres: [
  {id: 1, name: 'Mystery'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Thriller'},
],
```

to this:

```json
genres: ['Mystery', 'Thriller'],
```

So I did something which I believe is quite common in Javascript :

```js
movies.map((movie) => {
  movie.genres = movie.genres.map(g => g.name);
  movie.actors = movie.actors.map(a => a.name);
  return movie;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(movies));
```

However, once printed to the console, the array is completely unchanged. To have the desired effect on this array, I had to convert it into a string of characters and back into an array before performing the `map()` operations, like so:

```js
movies = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(movies));
movies.map((movie) => {
  movie.genres = movie.genres.map(g => g.name);
  movie.actors = movie.actors.map(a => a.name);
  return movie;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(movies));
```

Why did it work ? I'm guessing that doing this conversion back and forth removed certain fields from the object, but I do not see how this could've had an effect on the array.

EDIT: using other methods like `Array.from` or the spread operator (`movies = [...movies]`) does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Sequelize, but my best guess is that when you run `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`, you create a copy of the value returned from Sequelize. When you create a copy, your code then "owns" the new object, thus allowing changes to be applied.

Comment: And what would be a "clean" way of owning the array? Using `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` doesn't sound like good practice.

Comment: Actually, `JSON.parse` then `JSON.stringify` is a favorable way of copying a object. You could also use `copy = structuredClone(obj)` (new browsers only), or a package such as Lodash and `just-clone` could help too. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/122704/14884338

Answer (score 1):

If your `optionsArray` argument includes the `'IMMUTABLE'` option then it's working as designed.

If you want to check it (not to solve anything but just to feel a little more sane) then you can probably verify immutability by seeing
what [Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor)(movies, 'genres') returns.

In which case, yes, creating a copy of the object is best. If you ascribe to functional programming, it's the "right" way to do it. Never changing objects but instead returning new ones is a fundamental practice of functional programming and avoids entire categories of programming errors.

sean-777 is right, you can clone it using several different libraries, or [structuredClone()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone). In the case of your example, I'd probably just go with

```
function getName({name}) { return name; }
function mapName(a) {
  a.map(getName);
}
function convertMovie(movie) {
  return {
    ...movie,
    genres: mapName(movie.genres),
    actors: mapName(movie.actors)
  };
}
function convertMovies(movies) {
  return movies.map(convertMovie)
}
const moviesConverted = convertMovies(movies);
console.log(JSON.stringify(moviesConverted));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [structuredClone()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) method which creates a deep clone of a given value using the structured clone algorithm.

Demo **:**

```js
const jsObj = [
  {
    name: 'alpha',
    director: 'beta',
    genres: [
      {id: 1, name: 'Mystery'},
      {id: 2, name: 'Thriller'},
    ],
  }
];

const clonedObj = structuredClone(jsObj);

const modifiedObj = clonedObj.map(obj => {
    obj.genres = obj.genres.map(genreObj => genreObj.name)
  return obj;
});

console.log(jsObj);
console.log(modifiedObj);
```

Comment: Thanks, however this function is only available for Node 17 (not before)